# Exceeding speed of light in simple mechanical setup

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, speed-of-light, string

Suppose a system as shown. If i pull block $m1$ and $m2$ (the two side masses) with speed $v$ and theta is the angle mentioned the speed of central block becomes vsectheta in vertical direction. If theta approaches $pi/2$ then speed of central mass EXCEEDS SPEED OF LIGHT? how? From where did i get enough energy of $(1/2) m c^2$ to take central block to that speed??
This can be extended to any setup where we get sec theta as a multiplier. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: You are using Newtonian physics to get this result which is not going to work.  You need to use Special Relativity.

Comment: How to use relativity here?

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots

Comment: v and v' the wrong way round in your formula.  Nothing to do with relativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Leaving aside relativistic effects, as theta increases, the force you need to apply to move the outer blocks at a constant speed to raise the inner block increases more rapidly than sec theta, so the required force would approach infinity as theta approached a right angle. When you add in relativistic effects, the force would rise even more rapidly. In reality, for any finite force, theta would never reach a right angle, and in any case the apparatus would break under the strain.